# Is my well pump filled with sediment?

Tags: well, well-pump

Recently our well pump has been very loud. The duration and frequency of the pump activity hasn't increased but it is noticeably louder. Upon inspection I noticed that the lines feeding to and from the pump seem to show some possible build up on the inside. There is no filter in the system that I can tell, but the water colour/taste/smell/pressure in the house is good.

[image: Image of clear reinforced hose]
Is this just normal build up on the inside of the line or should I be concerned?

[image: Image of a jet pump beside a blue charge tank]

New homeowner, I don't know the history or age of this install.
Thanks for the responses!

Comment: Fill a clear container with water and leave sitting, any sediment should go to the bottom.  Turn off power to the pump and disconnect some lines to check inside.  Should have most of the pipe open.

Comment: Abnormal in the extreme to use clear tubing like that - for one thing, because it promotes algae growth, which might well be what you are seeing there. No shortage of variety in pipes - that hose, galvanized, copper...probably some galvanic action going on with all that.

Comment: Overtime, vibration can loosen screws and rivets.  That would result in louder operation.   Check all the fasteners for tightness and look for anything loose that may be vibrating.

Answer (score 1):

Most well casings are “steel pipe” this pipe rusts and even with filters the clear poly tubing will become dark like yours. Pumps do wear out and or need servicing depending on the age of the pump it may be time for bearings. If you were getting substantial amounts of sediment your would probably notice or smell it in the water.